# Unable to Install the Charles Proxy profile on Apple TV via Apple Configurator 2

Tags: tvos, http-proxy, apple-tv, charles-proxy, apple-configurator

I have been trying [this official guide](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) to setup Charles Proxy on my Apple TV (4th Gen, running tvOS 13.3). After creating the profile on Apple Configurator 2, I was performing the steps for setting up the profile on Apple TV below:

[image: Install Profile Screen]
[image]
[image]

After pressing "Done" above, this screen shows up indicating that no profile has been installed:

[image]

Can you guide me on how I can successfully install the Charles Proxy profile on my Apple TV running tvOS 13.3?

Answer (score 1):

This guide worked for me from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89603

Before doing the steps, you need a wired ethernet connection works in the same subnet of your iMac or Macbook. I just connected the Apple TV 4k to the ethernet port of my router.

1. On the Apple TV, navigate to the settings pannel to erase and restore the device. This erases any data from the Apple TV.
2. Remove the pared Apple TV from Apple Configurator 2 paired device list.
3. Just after rebooting Apple TV 4k, DO NOT perform any configuration or touch the remote controller. Open 'paired device' window of configurator 2. You will see the device showed as connected and find the Pair Device button.
4. Pair the device from this point. You will get a verification code prompt on the TV. Enter the code to configurator 2 and you will get your apple TV paired before activation.
5. In Apple configurator, select the Apple TV 4k device and then click Prepare. Follow the instruction to select 'No MDM', 'No DEP', generate organization certificate and then run the preparation.

Comment: Hi, I tried your steps and it says: "A cloud configuration is already present on this device. [MCTunnelErrorDomain – 0x36B2 (14002)]"

Comment: Why would I want to erase and restore the apple tv? This doesn't seem very practical

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@rwgrier/setting-up-charles-proxy-on-apple-tv-tvos-1ce64ee39b07) to set up Charles on my apple tv (running tvOS 14.3).

I ran into the exact same issue as you. I was able to resolve it by running through the steps on the blog and following the advice of the first comment left on the blog:

> Check the “supervise device” under the prepare phase. Otherwise tvOS
> won’t allow you to install an unsigned profile

This worked for me. Hope it helps anyone who runs into this in the future :)

Comment: Thanks! There's also a more detailed explanation of this here https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/a-how-to-guide-for-apply-tv-setup-with-charles-proxy

Answer (score 0):

You need to update both mac and appletv to latest versions. Apple in general pretty sensitive to version matches.